Mocking in a Jest Environment - AWS S3 Methods - Upload and getSignedUrl
file.js
/**
 * Uploads a file to an S3 bucket.
 * @param {string} bucketName - The name of the S3 bucket.
 * @param {string} key - The key under which to store the file in the S3 bucket.
 * @param {Object} body - The content of the file to be uploaded (should be JSON serializable).
 * @param {string} contentType - The MIME type of the content.
 * @returns {Promise<Object>} - A promise that resolves with the S3 upload response data.
 */
async function uploadToS3 (bucketName, key, body, contentType) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const params = {
            Bucket: bucketName,
            Key: key,
            Body: JSON.stringify(body),
            ContentType: contentType,
            ContentDisposition: "inline" // Display file in browser
        };

        s3.upload(params, (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
                logger.error("Error uploading to S3:", err);
                reject(err);
            } else {
                logger.debug("Uploaded to S3:", data);
                resolve(data);
            }
        });
    });
}


/**
 * Generates a pre-signed URL for accessing an object in an S3 bucket.
 *
 * @param {string} bucketName - The name of the S3 bucket.
 * @param {string} key - The key of the object in the S3 bucket.
 * @returns {Promise<string>} A promise that resolves with the pre-signed URL.
 */
async function generateSignedUrl (bucketName, key) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        s3.getSignedUrl("getObject", {
            Bucket: bucketName,
            Key: key,
            Expires: PRE_SIGNED_URL_EXPIRATION_TIME // URL expiration time in seconds
        }, (err, signedUrl) => {
            if (err) {
                logger.error("Error generating pre-signed URL:", err);
                reject(err);
            } else {
                logger.debug("Pre-signed `getObject` URL generated.");
                resolve(signedUrl);
            }
        });
    });
}

/**
 * Uploads a response to an S3 bucket and generates a pre-signed URL for accessing it.
 *
 * @param {string} service - The service name.
 * @param {string} build - The build identifier.
 * @param {Object} body - The content of the response to be uploaded.
 * @param {string} format - The format of the response ("html" or "json").
 * @returns {Promise<string>} A promise that resolves with the pre-signed URL of the uploaded response.
 * @throws {Error} Throws an error if there is any issue with S3 operations.
 */
async function uploadAndGenerateSignedUrl (service, build, body, format) {
    try {
        const key = `${service}/${build}_response.${format}`;   // Construct key for the S3 object based on response type
        const contentType = format === "html" ? "text/html" : "application/json";

        // Upload to S3
        await uploadToS3(LAMBDA_RESP_BUCKET_NAME, key, body, contentType);
        logger.info("Upload to S3 completed.");

        // Generate pre-signed URL
        const signedUrl = await generateSignedUrl(LAMBDA_RESP_BUCKET_NAME, key);
        logger.info("Pre-signed URL generated.");
        return signedUrl;
    } catch (error) {
        logger.error("Error with S3 operations due to: ", error);
        throw error;
    }
}

app.get("myPath/some_build_no", function getTestResultForBuildHandler (req, res) {

    return invokeLambdaByEnvironment(`some_path/`).then((body) => {
        const htmlBody = prettyHtml(body);
        if (JSON.stringify(body).length > MAX_RESP_SIZE_THRESHOLD) {
            logger.warn("raw JSON results too large to return, returning a summary", {
                jsonBodyLength: JSON.stringify(body).length,
                service: req.params.service,
                build: req.params.build,
            });

            const service = req.params.service;
            const build = req.params.build;
            const format = req.query.format ? req.query.format.toLowerCase() : DEFAULT_FORMAT;

            uploadAndGenerateSignedUrl(service, build, body, format)
              .then((signedUrl) => {
                logger.info("Signed URL:", signedUrl);
                return redirectRequest(req, res, 302, signedUrl)    // redirect to signed URL by S3
              })
              .catch((error) => {
                logger.error("Upload and generate signed URL failed:", error);
                return endRequest(req, res, 500);   // Handle the error as needed
              });
        }else {
                // If size is less than 950000, return based on format
                if (req.query.format === "json") {
                    return endRequest(req, res, 200, body);
                } else if (req.query.format === "html") {
                    return endRequest(req, res, 200, htmlBody);
                } else {
                    return endRequest(req, res, 200, htmlBody); // Default to JSON if format is not specified or invalid
                }
            }
    }).catch((err) => {
        logger.error("failed to get results by build", {
            error: err,
        });
        logger.info("Returning 500 due to catch");
        return endRequest(req, res, 500);
    });
});

Context:
Here, function getTestResultForBuildHandler returns some response which it retrives from by invoking another lambda function. Let's say if size of that response is more than 1 mb then it stores that value in S3 bucket and generates Pre-signed url for the same and redirect the request to that link.
I need to write test case for scenario where lambda generates more than 1 mb response. Here is sample test file, but I got stuck.
file.test.js
"use strict";

jest.mock("aws-sdk/clients/lambda");
jest.mock("aws-sdk/clients/s3");

// Some other mocks here

// Set up the mock for S3 constructor
const mockS3Constructor = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
    return {
        upload: jest.fn(), // Mock the upload method
        getSignedUrl: jest.fn(), // Mock the getSignedUrl method
        promise: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
    }
});

describe("some_path", () => {
   test("should redirect to s3 bucket url if body is over 1mb", () => {
//            jest.setTimeout(30000);
            mockConductorLambda.mockImplementationOnce((params, cb) => {
                const conductorResponse = JSON.stringify({
                    // body generation here which is more than 1 mb
                });
                return cb(null, { Payload: conductorResponse });
            });

            mockS3Constructor().upload.mockImplementationOnce((params, callback) => {
                return callback(null, { Location: "https://example.com/pre-signed-url" });
            });

            mockS3Constructor().getSignedUrl.mockImplementationOnce((params, callback) => {
                return callback(null, "https://example.com/pre-signed-url");
            });

           // Mocking should work here - s3.upload and s3.getSignedUrl functions
           // also need handle await async if needed
           // Mocking the S3 methods for upload and getSignedUrl
//            AWS.S3.prototype.upload.mockImplementationOnce((params, callback) => {
//                callback(null, { Location: "https://example.com/pre-signed-url" });
//            });
//            AWS.S3.prototype.getSignedUrl.mockReturnValueOnce("https://example.com/pre-signed-url");


            return supertest(my_app)
                .get("/some path")
                .query({format: "html"})
                .expect(302);

        });
}


